# How to force make to restart and reload generated makefiles?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

The task at hand is the following: an external tool called in a recipe produces a makefile that should be included by make immediately. Then, another rule, using the data included generates further include files. Make should restart again, and only then process the further rules. Consider the following example:

```
$(info ------- Restart $(MAKE_RESTARTS))

all :

include a
include b

a : p
    touch a

b : a
    touch b
```

Works like this:

```
        touch p 
        make
        ------- Restart
        touch a
        touch b
        ------- Restart 1
        make: Nothing to be done for 'all'.
```

My problem is that the rule b needs the data included from a, but b is executed BEFORE including the updated version of a.
Make should be restarted before executing b. How can this be achieved? I'd like to see this:

```
        touch p 
        make
        ------- Restart
        touch a
        ------- Restart 1
        touch b
        ------- Restart 2
        make: Nothing to be done for 'all'.
```

It's easy to detect whether a was included or not, and the rule for b can be hidden when a is not included. This works for a clean build, but does not when a already exists on the disk from a previous build, and the rule is triggered because p was updated.
Only make knows, whether the rule a:p is up-to-date, it's not possible to check that with conditional expressions.

Is there a solution for this?

Update: based on the advice from @MadScientist, I made it working this way:

```
$(info ------- Restart $(MAKE_RESTARTS))

all :

include b
include a

a : p
    @echo rule A
    touch a
    $(eval upd=1)

b : a
    @echo rule B
    $(if $(upd),@echo b skipped,touch b)
```

And the output:

```
touch p
make   
------- Restart 
rule A
touch a
rule B
b skipped
------- Restart 1
rule B
touch b
------- Restart 2
```

Perfect! Thanks guys, Merry Xmas everybody.

Comment: Why do you need to `touch b` in the rule for `a`?  It should be sufficient to just update `a`, because `b` depends on `a` so `b` will appear out of date WRT `a`.  You shouldn't need to touch `b` here.

Comment: Good question. I was experimenting and left it there. Thanks for pointing it out, corrected!

Comment: Btw, if the order of the includes is reversed, it does not work. (include a / include b)
I have no idea, why, do you?

Comment: This is a bug in the current version of GNU make, where prerequisites of included files aren't always properly considered when deciding whether to re-exec.  It's been fixed already in the Git source and will be fixed in the next release of GNU make (your example works for me with Git HEAD).

Comment: Wow. I'm really grateful for your help! Wasted several hours with experimenting and trying to understand what's happening... Thanks!

Comment: After reversing all the includes, everything seems to be working. Quite annoying bug. My build system invokes generators that produce unknown sets of files. A make include is created each time with the list of all generated files. Make is restarted, the file is included, then inside make the file list is split for modules, and the module-specific includes are updated. Make restarts again, twice for each generator.
Works well, except when I started adding multiple generators, that included the files in order. If the includes are not reversed, make does not restart and works from old data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One solution is to invoke a sub-make to build `b`.  That sub-make will include the newer `a` and so will be correct.  I believe something like this will work (untested):

```
$(info ------- Restart $(MAKE_RESTARTS))
all :

include a
include b

a : p
        touch a

ifeq ($(filter real_b,$(MAKECMDGOALS)),)
b : a
        $(MAKE) real_b
endif

.PHONY: real_b
real_b:
        touch b
```

Another solution would be to ensure that `b` is *not* updated when `a` is updated.  Maybe something like this (again, not tested):

```
$(info ------- Restart $(MAKE_RESTARTS))
all :

include a
include b

BUILT_A =

a : p
        touch a
        $(eval BUILT_A = true)

b : a
        $(if $(BUILT_A),,touch b)
```

(a rare legitimate use of `eval` in a recipe!)  In this version if `a` is built, then `b` will not be touched.  This way after make re-execs itself it will include `a` and include `b`, then see `a` is up to date but see that `b` is out of date (because we skipped the build step the first time) and rebuild `b`: this time `b` will be updated because `a` was updated in the previous pass, then make will re-exec itself again.

Comment: Thanks! Recursive make I wanted to avoid, and this usage of eval in a recipe was new to me. Learned something again. Made some further modifications, see the question with the final code. Works perfectly. You're great!

Answer (score 2):

There's more than one way to do it (as there usually is with Make).

I'd do it this way: put the the `include b` statement in `a`.

```
$(info ------- Restart $(MAKE_RESTARTS))

all :

-include a


a : p
    touch a
    @echo -include b >> a

b : a
    touch b
```

Comment: Thanks for looking into this. The solution works for a clean build only. On repeated builds the "old" version of a includes b, the behavior is identical to that of the original code:

------- Restart 
included a
touch a
echo include b >>a
touch b
------- Restart 1
included a
make: Nothing to be done for 'all'.

The problem is that B is updated based on the old content of a, only then the new version of a is included.