# GNU make: mixing the $(file) function with external tools

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

The example below is directly from the GNU make manual:

```
program: $(OBJECTS)
        $(file >$@.in,$^)
        $(CMD) $(CMDFLAGS) @$@.in
        @rm $@.in
```

This works perfectly. However, if I reverse the order of $(file) and the external tool, the behavior is still the same: $(file) is executed first, and only then the external tool.

Is it possible to call an external tool in a recipe, and after the successful completion of the tool, use $(file) to process the log and create further files?

The external tool is a code generator that produces an unknown set of files. The recipe should parse the log file and create make include files. Works with echo/$(shell), but that's limited by the system command line length. Using a separate rule would certainly work, but can it be done in the same recipe?

Comment: "Possible" is a strong word. At the time of executing the recipes the dependency graph and variables are set. No way adding them to the *current* make invocation. But you should be able to have the tool generate a makefile including the generated dependencies, then invoke that recursively.

Comment: Hi Andreas, actually you can do that with GNU make, see another question from me with example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70398930/how-to-force-make-to-restart-and-reload-generated-makefiles.
The current version creates the includes with echo, that's what I want to transform to use $(file). It's faster and not limited by the system command line length.

Answer (score 2):

GNU make will always expand all variables and functions in the entire recipe up front, before it starts to invoke any commands in the recipe.  So you cannot have a `$(file ...)` function (for example) operate on the results of running some command in the same recipe.

So the short answer to your question is no, it can't be done in a single recipe the way you want.

Comment: Thanks, understood.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible, if you run the shell command using `$(shell` `)` rather than directly putting it in a recipe. I've been using following wrapper for it, which checks the error code and discards the result:

```
# Same as `$(shell ...)`, but triggers a error on failure.
ifeq ($(filter --trace,$(MAKEFLAGS)),)
override safe_shell = $(shell $1)$(if $(filter-out 0,$(.SHELLSTATUS)),$(error Unable to execute `$1`, status $(.SHELLSTATUS)))
else
override safe_shell = $(info Shell command: $1)$(shell $1)$(if $(filter-out 0,$(.SHELLSTATUS)),$(error Unable to execute `$1`, status $(.SHELLSTATUS)))
endif

# Same as `safe_shell`, but discards the output and expands to a single space.
override safe_shell_exec = $(call space,$(call safe_shell,$1))
```

Then `$(CMD) $(CMDFLAGS) @$@.in` becomes `$(call safe_shell_exec,$(CMD) $(CMDFLAGS) @$@.in)`.

Comment: Great idea, thanks! It works. Unfortunately, console output does not work... Or is it possible to somehow redirect the output from the tool to the console? $(shell) captures the output, it's not sent to the console.

Comment: @vjalle I'm not sure. You could try redirecting output to stderr.

Comment: Forgot to reply: redirecting to stderr works! thanks.